Number of different entries in a symmetric matrix
Coming from a combinatorial investigation of quadratic forms, I came across the following problem:
Given a symmetric matrix $A$ of size $k$, such that in each row (and thus in each column), each entry may occur at most twice, how many different entries must $A$ have, i.e. what is the least size of the set $\{a_{i, j}\mid i, j \in \{1, \ldots, k\}\}$?
It does not seem like a problem nobody has considered before to me, but I have not been able to find techniques that allow me to solve it (or at least, I haven't seen how to use them).
Thanks in advance!

First, looking at any single row, it is clear that you need at least $\lceil \frac{k}2 \rceil$ different entries. The following construction shows that this is sufficient.
For even $k = 2n$, consider the matrix
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
B & B\\
B & B
\end{pmatrix},\quad\text{where}\quad B=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1 & a_2 & \cdots & a_{n-1} & a_n\\
a_2 & a_3 & \cdots & a_n & a_1\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
a_{n-1} & a_n & \cdots & a_{n-3} & a_{n-2}\\
a_n & a_1 & \cdots & a_{n-2} & a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Clearly, $B$ has $n$ different entries in each row, so $A$ also has $n$ different entries in each row as well, and every entry appears exactly twice. Moreover, $B$ is symmetric, so $A$ is also symmetric.
For odd $k=2n-1$, just remove the last row and the last column of $A$ above.

Incidentally, your matrix $B$ is a Hankel matrix

@BenGrossmann That's right. A circulant matrix also works for this construction.

@Parnay That would work for the "at most twice" requirement, but not overall symmetry (as I noticed after writing my now-deleted comment)

Ah yes, you are right!
